# Criar nomes de coluna com espaços

Tags: r

Estou tentando criar um DF com colunas que contém espaços em seus nomes, mas está aparecendo um erro. Este é o DF que estou tentando criar:

```
MUNICIPIO <- c('BELO HORIZONTE','BRASILIA','JUIZ DE FORA','MANAUS','MONTES CLAROS','RECIFE','RIO DE JANEIRO','SALVADOR','SAO PAULO','UBERLANDIA')
BELO HORIZONTE <- c(0,700,250,1000,400,800,430,900,500,30)
```

Esta é mensagem de erro:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "BELO HORIZONTE"
```

Como faço para resolver este exemplo do meu problema? O DF que estou trabalhando possui diversas colunas como este exemplo, por isso gostaria de uma sugestão de solução que pudesse abranger várias colunas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso é escrever o nome da variável entre acentos graves:

```
MUNICIPIO <- c('BELO HORIZONTE', 'BRASILIA', 'JUIZ DE FORA', 'MANAUS', 
               'MONTES CLAROS', 'RECIFE', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', 'SALVADOR', 
               'SAO PAULO', 'UBERLANDIA')
`BELO HORIZONTE` <- c(0, 700, 250, 1000, 400, 800, 430, 900, 500, 30)
BRASILIA <- c(700, 0, 350, 1200, 50, 110, 780, 984, 1150, 5)
`JUIZ DE FORA` <- c(250, 350, 0, 200, 15, 260, 305, 412, 29, 102)
MANAUS <- c(1000, 1200, 200, 0, 77, 115, 225, 318, 412, 511)
`MONTES CLAROS` <- c(400, 50, 15, 77, 0, 88, 819, 733, 978, 1001)
RECIFE <- c(800, 110, 260, 115, 88, 0, 17, 3000, 1418, 735)
`RIO DE JANEIRO` <- c(430, 780, 305, 225, 819, 17, 0, 513, 701, 56)
SALVADOR <- c(900, 984, 412, 318, 733, 3000, 513, 0, 389, 499)
`SAO PAULO` <- c(500, 1150, 29, 412, 978, 1418, 701, 389, 0, 1113)
UBERLANDIA <- c(30, 5, 102, 511, 1001, 735, 56, 499, 1113, 0)
DADOS_2 <- data.frame(MUNICIPIO, `BELO HORIZONTE`, BRASILIA, `JUIZ DE FORA`,
                      MANAUS, `MONTES CLAROS`, RECIFE, `RIO DE JANEIRO`, 
                      SALVADOR, `SAO PAULO`, UBERLANDIA)
```

Não sei exatamente qual o motivo para fazer isso, pois o `R` vai perder a informação sobre os espaços caso seja criado um data frame com estes vetores:

```
names(DADOS_2)
 [1] "MUNICIPIO"      "BELO.HORIZONTE" "BRASILIA"       "JUIZ.DE.FORA"   "MANAUS"        
 [6] "MONTES.CLAROS"  "RECIFE"         "RIO.DE.JANEIRO" "SALVADOR"       "SAO.PAULO"     
[11] "UBERLANDIA"
```

Se o objetivo for usar estes nomes das cidades com espaço para alguma apresentação de resultados, recomendo mantê-los todos sem espaço nos nomes das colunas e nos objetos dentro do workspace. Deixe para ajeitar manualmente estes nomes apenas na apresentação de fato, como por exemplo nos labels de possíveis gráficos.

Comment: Vlw pela resposta, mas necessitarei do nome com espaço. O processo que estou construindo me exige dessa forma, uma vez que irei verificar as distâncias entre cidades (matriz), ou seja, cada coluna será uma cidade, conforme meu exemplo acima (em breve irei publicar um post com esta dúvida). Enfim, neste primeiro momento necessito o nome com o espaço.

Comment: Pode usar os acentos e trabalhar com o pacote `tibble`, ele é uma versão melhorada da `data.frame`. Ele melhora a apresentação quando você chama ela e também mantém os nomes separados. Só seguir o exemplo do @marcus-nunes e trocar `data.frame` por `tibble`. E antes baixar o pacote `tibble` se você não tiver, ele vem com o `tidyverse` também.